# I have problems with the coder

Tags: 7

i just install the coder and when i run:

```
drush drupalcs .
```

in my module folder i got the next errors what i must do in order to avoid these errors??

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): /home/giannis/.drush/coder/coder_sniffer/Drupal:1: parser error : Document is empty in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php on line 531
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file():  in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php on line 531
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php on line 531
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): /home/giannis/.drush/coder/coder_sniffer/Drupal:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php on line 531
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file():  in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php on line 531
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php on line 531
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHP_CodeSniffer_Exception' with message 'Ruleset /home/giannis/.drush/coder/coder_sniffer/Drupal is not valid' in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:533
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php(419): PHP_CodeSniffer->processRuleset('/home/giannis/....')
#1 /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(614): PHP_CodeSniffer->process(Array, Array, Array, false)
#2 /usr/bin/phpcs(37): PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->process()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php on line 533
PHP_CodeSniffer found at least one issue.                                                                                  [error]
```